# Version 1 (Time Based) UUID in C#

Tags: c#, .net, uuid

I am looking for a library to generate version 1 UUIDs in C#.
All I am finding are snippets online like https://gist.github.com/nberardi/3759706

Is there a de facto standard way of generating these? I am concerned that this is a very tricky algorithm and was looking for a well tested option.

Thanks.

Comment: Just P/Invoke [`UuidCreateSequential`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/rpcrt4.uuidcreatesequential)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you extract the creation timestamp from it? that link only talks about the MAC, but cannot see any reference to a timestamp

Comment: By definition, version 1 UUIDs are based on time. And `UuidCreateSequential` returns version 1 UUIDs (which is easily verified by looking at the bits of the UUID that indicate which version they are)

Comment: Thanks. tested the examples and they look OK.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use that code. I just found out it generates duplicates. I would use this updated version that checks for duplicates. 
https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra/blob/master/src/GuidGenerator.cs